# JavaScript game, sleep before preseeding to next code

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently makeing a text based RPG game and i want you to have a timer

Now you can spend as much time as you want to kill it. Thank you for response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for are the `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` methods.

Here is an example of how you might use it in your game, assuming you have a function called `killPlayer()`:

```
var timer;

if (spottedByGuard)
    timer = setTimeout(killPlayer, 10000);
}
```

and then in the event that the player successfully kills the guard you call `clearTimeout(timer)`. So maybe in your code it would look something like this:

```
else if (input == "kill guard with knife") {

    if (currentroom == "morgue" && knife == true) {
        $('<p>You attack the guard with a knife and killed him!</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);

        guarddead = true;

        clearTimeout(timer); //This is the added line of code.
    }
    else {
        $('<p>You can\'t do that.</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
    }
}
```

Just make sure your `timer` variable is in scope when you set it and also when you refer to it when the guard is killed.

[More info on these methods here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Hope this helps :)

---

## UPDATE RESPONDING TO OP's EDIT

### A little bit of background information

`setTimeout()` takes two parameters. The first is the function that you want to call when the timeout finishes, and the second is the length of time (in milliseconds) that you want it to timeout after. So for example if I wrote `setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);` then a function called `myFunction()` will be called after 5 seconds.

You could write the same code using an **anonymous inner function** like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {/*This is inside the anonymous function*/}, 5000);
```

That anonymous function would get called 5 seconds later.

You could also assign a variable to that `setTimeout` call like this

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {/*This is inside the anonymous function*/}, 5000);
```

Now, if you want to, you can cancel the countdown by calling `clearTimeout` and giving it your `timeout` variable.

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

---

### Now back to your code (Updated):

At the top of your code add this variable:

```
var timeout;
```

Code when you are in the room "morgue":

```
else if (input == "go south" && currentroom =="torture") {
    if (beenmorgue == true) {
        if (guarddead == false) {
            morgueguard = "The guard is still here!";

            timeout = setTimeout(function() { // Added these 
                $("#killself").fadeIn(3000);  // 4 lines
            },                                // of
            10000);                           // code
        } else {
            morgueguard = "The guard remains on the floor rotting in a cesspool of it's juices.";
        }
        $('<p>You are back in the morgue. To the north is the doorway to the room of strange devices. ' + morgueguard + '</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        currentroom = "morgue";
    } else {
        $("#area_morgue").clone().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        beenmorgue = true;
        currentroom = "morgue";

        timeout = setTimeout(function() { // Added these 
            $("#killself").fadeIn(3000);  // 4 lines
        },                                // of
        10000);                           // code
}
```

Code for when you kill the guard:

```
else if (input == "kill guard with knife") {
    if (currentroom == "morgue" && knife == true) {
        $('<p>You attack the guard with a knife and killed him!</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
        guarddead = true;
        
        clearTimeout(timeout); //Added this line of code

    } else {
        $('<p>You can\'t do that.</p>').insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000);
    }
}
```

When you enter the morgue, the timer will start. After 10 seconds `$(#killself").fadeIn(3000);` will get executed.

When the player types "kill guard with knife",`clearTimeout(timeout);` will be executed. If you want the timer to stop in other circumstances, (e.g. if the player types "kill self with knife") then just add that line of code.

Comment: OK, I'm at work at the moment so I can't play your game right now! But I've updated my answer in response to your edited question. Let me know if you still need help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I thought you just wanted a timer to happen when you get spotted by a guard. What has that got to do with picking up a paperclip? You don't need to send me all your files. Just post more of your code into your question so that I can see it all.

Comment: In your code you have `if (currentroom == "morgue")`. Inside that `if` statement you need to put my code, `timeout = setTimeout(function() { }, 10000);`. That is what starts the timer.

Where you have `if (input == "kill guard with knife")` then you need to put the `clearTimeout(timeout);`. That is what stops the timer. Do you understand that so far?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the guard kills the player?

Comment: See the updated section under **"Now back to your code"**

Comment: No problem dude! I'd appreciate it if you could upvote the answer as well just so I get those extra 10 points! :) Just leave a comment on this question when the game is finished and I'll give it a look. It looks great so far! Good work :)

Comment: You have accepted it. I think you can upvote it too using the up arrow.

Comment: Aha ok no problem. Thanks for trying anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is how I'd handle it. You have a function that calls itself for the countdown, re-assigning the timeout to a variable that stores it. To save yourself, you clear the timeout.

```js
var output = document.getElementById('countdown'),
  killTimeout

function playerDeath() {
  alert('You ded.')
}

function killPlayerCountdown(timeleft) {
  output.textContent = timeleft
  if (timeleft == 0) playerDeath()
  else killTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    killPlayerCountdown(--timeleft)
  }, 1000)
}

function savePlayer(){
  window.clearTimeout(killTimeout)
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  killPlayerCountdown(10)
  this.textContent = "Save Yourself!"
  this.onclick = savePlayer
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>

<button>Start</button>
```